GoJS `diagram.model.toJson()` is not not updating after change
I am using SvelteKit and GoJS
I've declared let diagram; before onMount(), and defined diagram = new go.Diagram('Diagram'); inside onMount()
and all other details after that, including:
diagram.addModelChangedListener((e) => {
            if (e.isTransactionFinished) {
                saveDiagramToLocalStorage(); 
            }
});

saveDiagramToLocalStorage();  is defined after onMount():
const saveDiagramToLocalStorage = () => {
        const modelAsJson = diagram.model.toJson();
        console.log('SaveDiagram', modelAsJson);    // no changes on current data
        localStorage.setItem('myDiagramModel', modelAsJson);
};

And its all working fine, the function saveDiagramToLocalStorage() is beeing called, but,
The issue is:
diagram.model.toJson(); is always returning the same data, in other words is not being updated after changes in diagram.
Except:
Adding new node or link. The new ones are added, but the existing ones are still not updated. (I'm calling diagram.selection.<some_data> and that's well updated, but the diagram.model.toJson() is not picking changes on the existing ones for some reason)
I've tried:

putting Diagram.rebuildParts() before diagram.model.toJson();
putting saveDiagramToLocalStorage() inside onMount


It was a binding issue
Do not use this for binding:
.bind('location', 'loc', go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify)

Always use go.GraphObject.make and makeTwoWay in your diagram.nodeTemplate to keep diagram.model fully updated with this kind of binding:
new go.Binding('location', 'loc', go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify)

Full context: (working example)
// +page.svelte / <script>
onMount(() => {
    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    diagram = $(go.Diagram, DiagramDiv);

    diagram.nodeTemplate = $(
        go.Node,
        'Auto',
        {
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        },
        new go.Binding('location', 'loc', go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify)
    )
});

